# group byとhavingを使った時のcount(*)が何をしているのかわからない

Tags: sql

このSQLを実行した際の`count(*)`がわかりません。

```
select name from users
group by belong
having count(*) >= 2
```

テーブルとデータは下記です。

```
create table users (
  id int,
  name varchar(60),
  belong int
);

insert into users values (1, "A", 102), (2, "B", 103), (3, "C", 102), (4, "D", 105), (5, "E", 103), (6, "F", 102), (7, "G", 104);
```

---

SQLはgroup byの後にhaving句が実行されるのが調べてわかりました。
ということは`select name from users group by belong`の結果をhaving句でさらに絞り込んでるんだとと思いたしかめてみました。

`select name from users group by belong`は下記になりました。
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c07780/5

| name |
| --- |
| A |
| B |
| G |
| D |

having句をつけるとこうなりました。
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c07780/6

| name |
| --- |
| A |
| B |

`select name from users group by belong`の結果からどうやって`count(*) >= 2`の条件を満たしたレコードが選ばれたんでしょうか？`select name from users group by belong`で取得したテーブルの`count(*)`は4にしかならないのでAとBだけが選ばれるに至った手順がわかりません。

[COUNT(*)　が何を意味しているのかわからない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/42915/count-%E3%81%8C%E4%BD%95%E3%82%92%E6%84%8F%E5%91%B3%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AE%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8F%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84)
上記URLも読みましたが、理解できず質問しました。

どなたかご教授お願いします。

Answer (score 2):

下記のクエリを実行してみたら分かるかと思いますが、

```
select name,belong,count(*) from users　group by belong
```

belongでグループ化した結果でname列のみを表示しているので分かりにくいですが、belongが102と103が2レコード以上の条件を満たしています。

Comment: 返信いただきありがとうございます。つまりcount(*)はgroup byで重複が取り除かれグループ化された結果のレコード数ではなくgroup byでグループ化される前のデータを使ってレコード数を数えているのでしょうか？

Comment: そういう事になると思います